# Datagridview To Return column values (To String?)

Tags: vb.net

i am trying to change datagridvalues in to string, when the form loads it works, once i click the cell of datagridview it returns back to show integer value which either 1 or 2.

```
If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
    Dim i As Integer
    Try
        i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
        vsalesId = DataGridView1.Item(1, i).Value
        ' vardate = DataGridView1.Item(2, i).Value
        receiptNumber_txt.Text = DataGridView1.Item(2, i).Value
        varVoidValid = ("select salesId, receiptNumber, IIf(voidTicket = 'VALID', 1, IIF(voidTicket = 'VOIDED', 2, ' ') As voidTicket from sales order by purchaseDate desc") = DataGridView1.Item(3, i).Value

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End If
```

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to provide more details as to what you are trying to do and what is not working. Your description of the problem makes no sense… _”i am trying to change datagridvalues in to string”_  … ? Once the grids cell is filled with a value, its underlying data “type” can not be simply “changed” to a different type as you describe. SO, it is unclear what you mean by this.

Comment: In addition, it is unclear what you mean by… _”once i click the cell of datagridview it returns back to show integer value which either 1 or 2.”_ … ? What was the value before you clicked the cell? Even though a cell value is a 1 or 2, does NOT necessarily mean those values are `integer` values, they may well be `strings.` I suggest you provide an example that clearly shows what you are wanting to achieve and what is not working as expected.

Comment: Lastly, it is unclear what the posted code is supposed to be doing. In its current form, the last line of code in the try portion could not possibly compile…`varVoidValid = ("select salesId, …` … there are two “=” equal signs sandwiched between to values…? It is unclear what the code is trying to accomplish there. Also, you should be aware that when you try to get a cells value like…`= DataGridView1.Item(1, i).Value` … then `Value` is going to return an `Object`. If you wanted a `string` version of that object, you would simply call `Value.ToString()` to get the objects `string` value.

Comment: I you intend to execute that Select statement somewhere, never concatenate strings in sql. Always use parameters.